# usage of bootstrap datetime picker with reactjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I am using reactjs in my application but here i am facing some problems with the third party plugins like bootstrap datetime picker,bootstrap-select and bootstrap-slider. On refresh only those components will be visible other wise cant see them in ui. I am referring plugins css and js files in my html file. Here my doubt is those references are not loading on navigating to one component to other. Is there any way to refer them directly to component, if not how can use them with my react.if my issues make sense to you, Can you help me out.

Note: 1.I have seen react-bootstrap-* plugins.

Here is my code:
 index.html

```
  <script src="js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


  <script src="js/scripts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="js/moment.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js">
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap-slider.min.js"></script>
```

reactcomponent.js:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';
import LoadingSpinner from '../LoadingSpinner';
import EmailSentOnEcCreation from '../Messages/EmailSentOnEcCreation';
import $ from 'jquery';
import '../scripts';
class AddCustomer extends Component {

constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
  errorMessage: '',
  "error": "",
  // will hold the results from our ajax call
  loading: false, // will be true when ajax request is running
  hideAlert: 'none',
  refType: this.props.drop,
  dropdownItems: ''
};
console.log(this.props);

this.createCustomer = this.createCustomer.bind(this);
this.clearState = this.clearState.bind(this);
}

clearState(event) {
this.setState({errorMessage: ''});
this.setState({hideAlert: 'none'});

}
 componentDidMount() {
  $('select.selectpicker').attr("style", "display: inline !important");

 }
   createCustomer(event) {
   this.setState({errorMessage: ''});

    event.preventDefault();

  let history = createHistory();
   console.log(this.refs);
   let params = {
  input: {
    "Name": this.refs.customerName.value,
    "Email": this.refs.customerEmail.value,
    "Mobile": this.refs.customerPhone.value,
    "DOB": this.refs.customerDOB.value,
    "Pincode": this.refs.customerPincode.value,
    "RegionalID": this.refs.customerID.value,
    "RegionalIDType": this.refs.customerIdType.value,
    "CreatedBy": sessionStorage.userID
  }
};
console.log(params);
axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = sessionStorage.token;
this.setState({
  loading: true
}, () => {
  axios(localStorage.baseUrl + 'ValueStat/secure/CustomerProfile', {
    method: "Post",
    data: params,
    withCredentials: true
  }).then(res => {
    console.log(res);

    if ($.isEmptyObject(res.data.errorMessage) === false) {
      for (var key in res.data.errorMessage) {
        console.log(res.data.errorMessage[key]);
        this.setState({errorMessage: res.data.errorMessage[key]})
        this.setState({loading: false});
        this.setState({hideAlert: 'block'});
      }
    } else if ($.isEmptyObject(res.data.message) === false) {
      //sessionStorage.setItem('otherNavigation',"EmailSent");
      for (var key in res.data.message) {
        console.log(res.data.message[key]);
        //  this.setState({errorMessage:res.data.message[key]})
        sessionStorage.setItem('message', res.data.message[key]);
        this.setState({hideAlert: 'block'});

        this.setState({loading: false});
      }

      sessionStorage.setItem('endCustomer', 
      JSON.stringify(res.data.output.CUSTOMER));

      this.setState({loading: false});
      $('#myModal').hide();
      $('.modal-backdrop').hide();
      this.props.history.push('/EmailSentOnEcCreation');
    }

  }).catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
    if (error.response.status == 401) {
      window.location.href = '/Logout';
    }
    //window.location.href = '/ErrorComponent';

    //sessionStorage.setItem('otherNavigation',"ErrorComponent");
    // this.state.history.go('/ErrorComponent');
  });
  });

   }

  render() {

const {loading} = this.state;
console.log(this.state);
return (<div>

  <div className="modal fade add-new-customer-modal" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div className="modal-dialog">
      <div className="modal-content">
        <div className="modal-header">
          <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 className="modal-title">ADD NEW CUSTOMER</h4>
        </div>
        <form onSubmit={this.createCustomer}>
          <div className="modal-body">

            <div className="row">
              {loading && <LoadingSpinner/>}
              <div className="alert alert-warning " style={{
                  "display" : this.state.hideAlert
                }}>
                <a href="#" className="close" aria-label="close" onClick={this.clearState}>×</a>
                {this.state.errorMessage}</div>
              <div className="col-md-6">

                <div className="form-group">
                  <label className="form-group-label pull-left">Customer Name</label>
                  <div>
                    <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Enter your Name" required="required" ref="customerName"/>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                  <label className="form-group-label pull-left">Phone Number</label>
                  <div>
                    <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Enter customer phone" required="required" ref="customerPhone"/>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                  <div className="row user-id-type-drop">
                    <label className="form-group-label pull-left">User's ID Type</label>
                  </div>
                  <div className="row user-id-type-drop">
                    <select id="sel2" className="selectpicker custom-drop-id-type form-control custom-drop" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" data-style="btn-primary" ref="customerIdType">
                      <option value="-1" className="cust-op">Select</option>

                      {
                        this.state.refType.map((e, key) => {
                          return <option className="cust-op" key={key} value={e.id}>{e.typeName}</option>;
                        })
                      }

                    </select>
                  </div>

                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                  <div className="row pull-left">
                    <div className="form-check pull-left">
                  <label className="checkbox-inline activate-user ">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="check"  value="1" ref="customerWebActivate" /> <span className=" activate-user-title label-text" >WEB ACTIVATE CUSTOMER</span>
                  </label>
                </div>

                  </div>
                </div>

              </div>
              <div className="col-md-6">
                <div className="form-group">
                  <label className=" form-group-label pull-left">Customer Email</label>
                  <div>
                    <input type="email" className="form-control" placeholder="Enter customer Email Address" required="required" ref="customerEmail"/>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                  <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-md-6">
                      <label className=" form-group-label pull-left">Date of Birth</label>
                      <div>
                        <input type="text" id='datetimepicker7' className="form-control" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" required="required" ref="customerDOB"/>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-6">
                      <label className=" form-group-label pull-left">Pincode</label>
                      <div>
                        <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="000000" required="required" ref="customerPincode"/>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                  <label className=" form-group-label pull-left">User ID</label>
                  <div>
                    <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="User Identification Number" required="required" ref="customerID"/>
                  </div>
                </div>

              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
          <div className="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" className="btn-add-newCustomer-cancel" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            <button type="submit" className=" btn-add-newCustomer">Continue</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  </div>);
 }
}
export default AddCustomer;
```

public folder>js>Script.js :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.dropdown-menu a').click(function(){
$('#selected').text($(this).text());
 });

  $(function () {
    $("#ex13").slider({
                ticks: [1, 5 , 10,15, 20, 25,30,35,40,45,50,55,60,65],
                range:true,
                max:5,
                min:1,
                value: [1, 10],
                ticks_labels: ["1 year", "5 years", "10 years", "15 years", "20 years","25 years","30 years","35 years","40 years","45 years","50 years","55 years","60 years","65 years"],
                ticks_snap_bounds: 30
            });
      $('#datetimepicker7').datetimepicker({
          useCurrent: false, //Important! See issue #1075
          format: "dd MM yyyy",
          minView: 2, startView: 2
      });


      $("#datetimepicker7").on("dp.change", function (e) {
          $('#datetimepicker6').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(e.date);
      });
  });
```

});

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please include some code, or other information so that we can answer the question. It's too vague.

Comment: react-bootstrap plugins that you saw didnt work for you?

Comment: @G_S:  React-bootstrap-* plugins works  but why cant we use  jquery third party plugins what if we dont have react-bootstrap-* plugins

Comment: @Tolsee updated my query with code

Comment: Well jquery third party plugins can be used. Just trying to see why you had to use them when we already have components ready.

Comment: You are loading jQuery as a global and as a module. In fact, you very likely have 2 versions of it in play depending. That may be what you want but it may not.